# Intel compiler doesn't recognise identifiers from gcc' avxintrin.h

Tags: c++, gcc, avx, icc

I am trying to enable AVX instructions in my project. I can build it with gcc (*gcc -mavx*), but not with Intel compiler (*icpc -maxv*) which fails in avxintrin.h gcc header with the following errors:

- no declaration for "__m256d" identifier
- "__builtin_ia32_loadupd256" is undefined

Just for reference, here is the code from avxintrin.h:

`extern __inline __m256d __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
_mm256_loadu_pd (double const *__P)
{
   return (__m256d) __builtin_ia32_loadupd256 (__P);
}`

As I understand it, those identifiers are built-in functions in gcc, which is why are not recognised by icc; and I guess I should somehow hide avxintrin.h header from icc and make it use its own built-ins ("intrinsics"). Am I correct, and how can I make icpc work?

gcc 4.4.7, icpc 17.0

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using headers from such an old version of gcc with ICC?  The GCC 4.4 series predates AVX.  (4.4.7 is from 2012, but it's still relatively ancient).  Current GCC is 8.2, or 7.4 for the old-stable.  (If you care about how well GCC tunes for modern CPUs, especially with AVX, use a newer GCC that knows `-march=skylake` and `-march=znver1`).

ICC *does* depend on GCC headers for some reason, apparently including for `immintrin.h`.  IDK why ICC doesn't fully provide their own definitions for Intel intrinsics.

**A working install of ICC17 *does* understand that GCC builtin, after you `#include <immintrin.h>`. https://godbolt.org/z/PKumZx.**   But that's with a more recent `immintrin.h`, I think.

And unlike ICC17, ICC19 will compile a `__builtin_ia32_loadupd256(p)` for `double*p` even with no declarations or includes.

ICC complains if you declare you own `__m256d` unless you put the `__attribute__` in the right order, etc. Anyway, try grabbing headers from a newer gcc, **your ICC might be too new for that gcc**.

---

Also, don't include `avxintrin.h` directly, include `immintrin.h`.

avxintrin.h from gcc8.2 has an ifdef for `# error "Never use <avxintrin.h> directly; include <immintrin.h> instead."`.  Maybe your old gcc version is missing that.

Comment: I am looking for solution for these compilers, can't upgrade them... I don't include avxintrin directly, just saying that the error comes from it.

Comment: @me76: A working install of ICC17 *does* understand that GCC builtin, after you `#include <immintrin.h>`.  https://godbolt.org/z/PKumZx.  And ICC19 will compile a `__builtin_ia32_loadupd256(p)` for `double*p` even with no declarations or includes.  But that's with a more recent immintrin.h, I think.  Maybe ICC doesn't actually provide all its own headers, and depends on some from gcc.  It complains if you declare you own `__m256d` unless you put the `__attribute__` in the right order, etc.  Anyway, try grabbing headers from a newer gcc, your ICC might be too new for that gcc.

Comment: The thing is, none of those headers and functions/typedefs are explicitly included in our source code. The error is triggered purely by _-mavx_ option, which makes compiler use _immintrin.h_ from some of the library files (e.g. one such include is found in tbb header _tbb/machine/gcc_itsx.h_

Comment: Wow, GCC 4.4.7 is from 2012 and GCC 4.4 predates AVX! I'd be surprised if a 5 years newer ICC would even work at all with it - let alone correctly. You're better off asking on the Intel forums. Though they're probably just gonna tell you the same thing that you don't want to hear: "Your GCC is too old."

Comment: @Mysticial I just checked the header file for gcc 4.8, it has the same built-ins, which means that Intel compiler would have failed with gcc 4.8 too.

Comment: @me76 I'm not sure I'd jump to that conclusion so quickly. There's probably a lot more to the ICC/GCC integration than just the header files. Though I'm saying that without knowing much about how that integration even works. At least in Windows, ICC reroutes a lot of things to its own headers thereby ignoring the MSVC headers. Not sure if it's any different on Linux/GCC.

Comment: @Mysticial thank you for your comments - they helped me find a workaround! I  disabled inclusion of immintrin.h by defining _IMMINTRIN_H_INCLUDED on command line, and it worked! Now have to see if icc can use its intrinsic identifiers without gcc's headers (in theory it should).

Comment: That didn't work :(  I compiled a small test where I included only immintrin.h and passed only Intel include dir to icc - for headers included from within immintrin.h, icc stil was picking them from gcc directory...  Does it use some environment variables to resolve include directories?